# Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) - Data messages are CANCELED by iOS device after restart until app is opened for the first time after device restart

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using pure data messages from FCM to display notifications locally on my app devices. For some reason, on iOS devices only, the data messages are CANCELED by iOS whenever the device is restarted up until my app is opened for the first time.  This leads to my app not receiving any data messages and thus not being able to display notifications and process them accordingly.  I am using React Native / Expo to build my app.

This below log lines show iOS cancellations, which continue to retry until the app is opened for the first time following the restart.

iOS Logs:

```
default 16:57:19.114198+0100    dasd    Submitted Activity: com.apple.pushLaunch.XXXXXXXXXXXXXX at priority 5 (Fri Dec 30 16:57:19 2022 - Sat Dec 31 16:57:19 2022)
default 16:57:19.118067+0100    dasd    Daemon Canceling Activities: {(
    com.apple.pushLaunch.XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
)}
default 16:57:19.118227+0100    dasd    CANCELED: com.apple.pushLaunch.XXXXXXXXXXXXXX at priority 5 <private>!
default 17:16:58.004240+0100    dasd    com.apple.pushLaunch.XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:[
    {name: ApplicationPolicy, policyWeight: 50.000, response: {Decision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{[pushDisallowed]: Required:0.00, Observed:1.00},]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed}
```

Once the app is started for the first time, the data messages are received by my app. Following this, the issue does not take place once the app has been started the first time, even if it is is subsequently killed. However, on the next restart, the same issue will take place once again.

The following data message is sent using firebase admin sdk:

```
       Message firebaseMessage = Message.builder()
                .putData("notificationId", notificationId)
                .putData("title", title)
                .putData("body", message)
                .putData("imageUrl", imageUrl)
                .putData("channelImageUrl", channelImageUrl)
                .putData("channelId", "channel-notifications")
                .setApnsConfig(ApnsConfig.builder()
                        .setAps(Aps.builder()
                                .setContentAvailable(true).build())
                        .putHeader("apns-push-type", "background")
                        .putHeader("apns-priority", "5")
                        .putHeader("apns-topic", <my-app-bundle-id>)
                        .build())
                .setAndroidConfig(AndroidConfig.builder()
                        .setPriority(AndroidConfig.Priority.HIGH)
                        .build())
                .setToken(recipient)
                .build();
```

The issue does not occur on Android.

Does anyone know what could be wrong and how to fix for my app to start receiving data messages even after a restart on iOS?